# Help getting mini-DisplayPort external monitor working on Lenovo T440s ( Intel HD 4400)

Tags: intel-graphics, lenovo, external-monitor, displayport

I have the following setup:

- Lenovo T440s running Ubuntu 15.04 (upgraded from 14.10)
- Asus PB278Q (supports DisplayPort 1.2)
- AmazonBasics mini-DisplayPort to DisplayPort cable

System information:

```
$ inxi -Fx
System:    Host: bipinnate Kernel: 3.19.0-18-generic x86_64 (64 bit gcc: 4.9.2)
           Desktop: Unity 7.3.2 (Gtk 3.14.12) Distro: Ubuntu 15.04 vivid
Machine:   System: LENOVO product: 20AQCTO1WW v: ThinkPad T440s
           Mobo: LENOVO model: 20AQCTO1WW v: SDK0E50510 PRO
           Bios: LENOVO v: GJET72WW (2.22 ) date: 02/21/2014
CPU:       Dual core Intel Core i7-4600U (-HT-MCP-) cache: 4096 KB
           flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx) bmips: 10774
           clock speeds: max: 3300 MHz 1: 2761 MHz 2: 2406 MHz 3: 2099 MHz
           4: 2053 MHz
Graphics:  Card: Intel Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller
           bus-ID: 00:02.0
           Display Server: X.Org 1.17.1 drivers: intel (unloaded: fbdev,vesa)
           Resolution: 1920x1080@60.0hz
           GLX Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel Haswell Mobile
           GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 10.5.2 Direct Rendering: Yes
Audio:     Card-1 Intel 8 Series HD Audio Controller
           driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:1b.0
           Card-2 Intel Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller
           driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:03.0
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k3.19.0-18-generic
Network:   Card-1: Intel Ethernet Connection I218-LM
           driver: e1000e v: 2.3.2-k port: 3080 bus-ID: 00:19.0
           IF: eth0 state: down mac: 28:d2:44:75:99:2e
           Card-2: Intel Wireless 7260
           driver: iwlwifi v: in-tree: bus-ID: 03:00.0
           IF: wlan0 state: up mac: 7c:7a:91:97:1a:9e
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 512.1GB (25.1% used)
           ID-1: /dev/sda model: SAMSUNG_MZ7TD256 size: 256.1GB temp: 0C
           ID-2: /dev/sdb model: TS256GMTS400 size: 256.1GB temp: 45C
Partition: ID-1: / size: 211G used: 113G (57%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sdb2
           ID-2: swap-1 size: 8.00GB used: 0.00GB (0%) fs: swap dev: /dev/sdb1
RAID:      No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 49.0C mobo: N/A
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: 0
Info:      Processes: 203 Uptime: 5:28 Memory: 1183.5/11900.9MB
           Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Gcc sys: 4.9.2
           Client: Shell (bash 4.3.301) inxi: 2.2.16
```

I would like to use the Asus external monitor with this laptop. However, when I plug it in, it seems to not be detected. Clicking "Detect Displays" in the displays prompt yields nothing, and eventually the monitor goes to standby.

I have had success using the VGA port at low resolutions for giving presentations and such, but I need to get DisplayPort working to drive this monitor. Is this a driver issue of some sort?

Comment: Your monitor  has resolution of 2560 x 1440  or  3840 x 2160 ?

Comment: please attach your /var/log/Xorg.0.log so we can see what ubuntu has managed to understand about your display hardware

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade && sudo shutdown -r now
```

Plug the cable on the display, open a terminal, type:

```
tail -f /var/log/{messages,kernel,dmesg,syslog}
```

Plug the cable to the ultra book and see if you get some sort of output.
just to see if the cable works.

```
sudo apt-get install arandr
```

Use `arandr` to set the output.